# Divide and conquer algorithm to compute friend points

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem which required to solve by divide and conquer.
There is a set S including N points.
If there is a square parallel to the axis, only two points p1 and p2 in S are contained, then we called p1 and p2 friend points.

Now, I need to use Divide and conquer algorithm to compute how many friend points in S.

I have thought long time. I have no ways.
I need your help.
My English is bad, if you have problems ,Please ask me, I wll add. Thansks.

Comment: Can a given point be friend of more than one other point? Imagine a set of three points at p1=(-1, 0), p2=(0, 0) and p3=(+1, 0). Would this set have just two friend points? Or would there be two pairs of friends {p1, p2} and {p2, p3} and thus three friend points?

Comment: A given point be friend of more than one other point

Comment: If points can be friends of more than one other point, the best algorithm is to construct a [Voronoi Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). A given point is then friend of all other points located in adjacent Voronoi areas. A divide and conquer algorithm is described [here](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/Voronoi/DivConqVor/divConqVor.htm).Closely related to the Voronoi Diagram is a [Delauney Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). It connects adjacent Voronoi points and can thus be seen as "Friendship Diagram".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to divide in such a way that the individual parts are smaller and can be treated independently. We could divide the points into two sets using a pivot similar to quicksort. But it is way more difficult than it sounds, because if not done correctly the sets may not shrink on special cases or are not independent.

**Adding friends**: The sizes of the sets which have to be evaluated because they cannot be devided any further are 1 (do nothing), 2 (add pair) and 3 (add the 2 to 3 pairs, checks required).

**Finding a pivot**: Calculate the mean x and mean y and find the point `p` closest to it.

**Divide**: Divide the points into 4 sets a, b, c and d as follows. a, b is a bottom left, top right partitioning and c, d a top left, bottom right partitioning, only keep the better one (take a, b if a.size + b.size <= c.size + d.size). This should ensure that the largest undevidable set has a size of 3 even on special cases (I'm not 100% positive about that, but the algorithm stays the same if it should be larger, just more base cases where friends are added). All sets include the pivot and other points as follows: set a: x <= p.x || y < p.y, set b: x > p.x || y >= p.y, set c: x < p.x || y >= p.y and set d: x >= p.x || y < p.y. We should end up with two sets that both have about 1/2 to 3/4 of the total points and can be treated independently. So with this algorithm a pair of friends may be detected more than once.

Example:

```
* * *    * * *    * * .   * * *
* * * => * p * => * * . , . * * bottom-left top-right partition
* * *    * * *    * * *   . * *

* * .    * * .    * * .   . . .
* * . => * p . => * * . , * * . top-left bottom-right partition
* * *    * * *    * . .   * * *

. . .    . . .    . . .   . . .
* * . => * * . => * . . , . * * bottom-left top-right partition
* * *    * p *    * * *   . * .
```

and so on... simplified:

```
a | b    top-left bottom-right partition: 1st set: a, b, c, p; 2nd set: b, c, d, p.
- p -
c | d    bottom-left top-right partition: 1st set: a, c, d, p; 2nd set: a, b, d, p.
```

The groups are independent because points in ad and cb cannot be friends, p will always be in the way. The top-left bottom-right partition seperates points a from d and the bottom-left top-right partition seperates points b from c.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your divide. Can you give an example?

Comment: added an example

Comment: The partition  b and c will be compute twice.

Comment: You will get two sets with about 3/4 of the points, so yes some pairs are detected twice, it's all above, but the sets are independent and they are getting smaller. If you add the friends to a set then it doesn't matter at all, duplicates will be discarded automatically. Do this 10 times recursively and the size of the sets is about 2 millionth of the total amount points.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following (not necessarily optimal) algorithm in pseudo code?

```
List<Pair<Point, Point>> findFriends(List<Point> points)
{
    List<Pair<Point, Point>> friends = new List<Pair<Point, Point>>();

    if (points.Count > 1)
    {
        if (points.Count == 2)
        {
           friends.Add(new Pair<Point, Point>(points[0], points[1]);
        }
        else
        {
           int xMedian = getMedianX(points);
           int yMedian = getMedianY(points);
           List<Point> topLeftPoints = selectPoints(points, 0, xMedian-1, yMedian, yMax);
           List<Point> bottomLeftPoints = selectPoints(points, 0, xMedian-1, 0, yMedian-1);
           List<Point> topRightPoints = selectPoints(points, xMedian, xMax, yMedian, yMax);
           List<Point> bottomRightPoints = selectPoints(points, xMedian, xMax, yMedian, yMax);

           friends.Add(findFriends(topLeftPoints));
           friends.Add(findFriends(bottomLeftPoints));
           friends.Add(findFriends(topRightPoints));
           friends.Add(findFriends(bottomRightPoints));      
        }
    }

    return friends;
}
```

Comment: With this implementation you will miss all the friends which are in different sets after the split. Imagine points on (-2, 1); (-1, 2); (1, 2); (2, 1); (2, -1); (1, -2); (-1, -2), (-2, -1). An octagon, e.g. (-1, 2) and (-1, -2) will be missed... pretty tricky.

Comment: @maraca: yes, that is what I have meant with "non optimal". Any suggestions for improvement?